# Xpath Get value of current node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following xml and want to get the attribute `(identifier='content')` value for the attribute `(identifier='id')` with `id` 510 with the help of xpath.

```
<product id='1'>
    <row='1'>
    <attribute identifier='id'>510</attribute>
    <attribute identifier='content'>Test 1</attribute>  
    </row>
    <row='2'>
        <attribute identifier='id'>100</attribute>
        <attribute identifier='content'>Test 2</attribute>
    </row>
    ...
</product>
```

I tried it with:

```
product[@id='1']/row/attribute[@identifier='id' and text()='510']
```

But as I already know this returns only the content of the attribute with `identifier='id'`.
How to get the value of `identifier='content'` where identifier `'id'= 510`?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is no XML, something's very wrong with your `<row/>` elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the value of the `attribute` element named `content` for a row that has an `id` of 510:

```
//product[@id='1']/row[attribute[@identifier='id'] = '510']/attribute[@identifier='content']
```

The nested predicate selects `attribute` elements whose `identifier` is `id` and checks whether any of them has the value 510.